# Querying other collection inside forEach for Mongo DB and Node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am facing issue when I call mongoDB `find()` query in side another find query
Here I am notable to send response value to postman but its showing in my console:

```js
email = req.body.email;
role = req.body.role;
console.log("id",email)
let result = db.collection('deliveryBoy').find({ 
    DeliveryBoyEmail: email,
    DeliveryBoyrole: role
}).toArray();
var arr=[]
result.forEach((docs) => {
    db.collection('consumers').find({
        _id: new MongoClient.ObjectID(docs.consumerId)
    })
    .forEach((v)=>{
        v['Customer_name'] = v.name;
        arr.push(v)
    }) 
})
console.log(arr)
res.send(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

use await before calling find method
and you can `return res.json(arr)` instead of calling `res.send(JSON.stringify(arr))`